# Django ModelForm float field not calling Clean_Field method

Tags: django, forms, modelform

i am having a unique kind of problem.
i am putting "$90" value in my floatField.
i assume it should be cleaned and stored as "90.0" in the model.

but when i input "$90" and call clean_filed method, it does not call that clean method. 
but when i apply the breakpoint on clean(self) mehthod and try to get its value, its says None.

please help me out. here is my code.

```
Model
class Project(models.Model):
foo = models.FloatField("foo",
        null=True, blank=True
    )


forms
widgets = {
         'foo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'currency': 'true'})}

    def clean_foo(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data.get('foo')
        print value # i get NONE here.............
        return value
```

Comment: Have you tried other inputs? Like "90" without the "$" sign or an already clean "90.0"? Try seeing if it's really a problem with the cleaning and not something else

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `clean_<field>` hooks in the forms API are for doing *additional* validation. It is called after the field calls its clean method. If the field does not consider the input valid then the `clean_<field>` is not called. This is noted in the custom validation docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/validation/

> For any field, if the Field.clean() method raises a ValidationError, any field-specific cleaning method is not called. However, the cleaning methods for all remaining fields are still executed.

In your case because `$90` does not validate as a float it will not be called. Instead what you should do is create a subclass of the `FloatField` which cleans the input (removing `$`, etc) prior to validating the input as a float.